# Handle an exception thrown from a CTOR?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

tl;dr

I want to do something like this:

```
foo()
{
  Y* p;
  try {
    p = new Y();
  } catch {
    //fix any problem that may have occured
  }
  // Now I know the object was fixed during catch or simply was created successfully.
  p.do_something();
  // win
}
```

The object I am creating is using an eternal resource that is sometimes unreliable. It is dangerous to attempt to allocate without necessary precautions. If it does fail, there are things that could be done. However it seems that throwing an exception unlike the switch statement I've show later, does not allow me to fix the problem AFAIK.

I have been advised to throw an exception from a constructors. However, I don't understand how that can prove to be useful because I don't see how that exception will be handled? I did a search and found [this example](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors-can-throw.html) but I am not sure if it's really a useful extendable way to handle construction failure.

example code:

```
void f()
{
  X x;             //← if X::X() throws, the memory for x itself will not leak
  Y* p = new Y();  //← if Y::Y() throws, the memory for *p itself will not leak
}
```

Lets say there were more instances on the heap that were allocated before `p`. Wouldn't they leak to memory because of this? So the function `f` is just used to construct an instance of `Y`. Would it not be always more useful to move the "dangerous" construction outside to another method?

What I normally do:

```
X* x = new X(); //No dangerous operation

switch (x.init()) // init returns int
  {
    case ...
    // Handle failed init() here
  }
```

Are there disadvantages to this? It seems more reliable.

Comment: Don't use `new`. Then the problem goes away.

Comment: Or, if you must use `new`, use a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, so that when you leave the scope, the memory is freed.

Comment: And even better would be to raii-wrap all resources, not only memory.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem in a constructor.  If you solve that by throwing an exception then you have two problems.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with new.  Even if you construct an object on the stack or insert one into a container, the constructor still executes.

Comment: What do you mean by extendable?  I'm not sure why you think there is not enough information in that article.  I googled c++ constructor exception and found quite a few articles and threads on the subject.  Without more information from you, I don't see how anyone can give you a more satisfying answer.

Comment: I basically want something like `X x = new X();` `if (x.is_no_good()) fix (x);` `continue doing what is needed..` An exception does not seem to allow that unlike the switch I wrote above where you can check the rv and fix the problem when possible. Plus, it seems an exception can cause memory leaks if other objects are allocated in that scope into the heap.

Comment: @shawn1874 I explained the challenge as best I can. I am not sure what more to add. I simply think that an external switch is more informative and accessible to the API user than it is easy to use an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (Resource acquisition is initialization) on each of the members. A destructor for an object is only called if the constructor has completed. That way, if only one of the two members' constructors is called, only that member's destructor will be called, in which any cleanup should be performed.

```
class Locked_file_handle {
    File_ptr p;
    unique_lock<mutex> lck;
public:
    X(const char* file, mutex& m)
        :p{file, "rw"},
        lck{m} 
    {}
    // ..
};
```

If an exception occurs after p has been constructed but before lck has been, then the destructor for p but not for lck will be invoked. Doing it this way will let the author of the constructor forgo writing explicit exception handling code.

Source : "The C++ Programming Language 4th edition" (Stroustrup)

Edit: So in your case, it would look like this

```
public class YHandle {
    Y* p;
    YHandle() {
        Y = new Y()
    }
    ~YHandle() {
        delete Y;
    }
}

foo() {
    YHandle p = YHandle();
    p.do_something();
} // p is deleted here
```

Comment: Could you comment what in this code sample is related to RAII and how so it could benefit people who may be confused by it? AFAIK RAII means that the lock needs to be released during the DTOR of X?

Comment: The only place an exception can occur in the constructor above is in one of the constructors for those two local objects - p and lck. We assume both of those object's destructors properly release any resources(which will vary based on the resource), or subsequently also use RAII on its members.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is safe, because if the c'tor throws an exception, the memory allocated for the object that failed to construct is freed before the exception is passed on. When the exception exits the `f` scope, the stack is unwound.

If a half-constructed-and-subsequently-having-its-members-and-bases-destructed object were returned to the calling scope, there would be no way for that scope to determine how to properly free that memory, so thankfully this isn't done.

If other objects are constructed on the heap in the same function, then the usual rules apply. In principle, you do not need to special-case c'tor calls here, and just pretend that the statement that throws is a regular function call.

Comment: However, inside the constructor the designer should still be attempting to ensure that resources are deallocated.  What if the constructor allocated 5 things, and then threw while doing a 6th thing?  A memory leak might occur then unless there is a try..catch in the constructor that does some cleaning before the rethrow.

Comment: Of course. The c'tor is no different from any other function in that regard.

Answer (score -1):

If the throw may cause a leak then it is your responsible te delete the allocation

you can roll the exception like this:

```
void f()
{
  X x;             //← if X::X() throws, the memory for x itself will not leak
  Y* p;
  try{  
    p = new Y();  //← if Y::Y() throws, the memory for *p itself will not leak
  } catch(exception &e){
    ///clean what you need

    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see now. but what is the point of throwing an exception if the underlying issue can't be resolved within the function? Is it not like wrapping the constructors with another abstraction that leaves the heavy lifting to someone else?

Comment: Because constructors cannot return values it's the most logical way to report failure.

Comment: Would it not be more logical to call a constructor that does not do anything "dangerous" and afterwards, call a public init() method that will return information (if it fails). I will add this to the question

Comment: Using an `init()` function is frowned upon, even by the language author Stroustrup himself. When the constructor finishes executing, you *should* be left with a perfectly usable object.

Comment: Using an init function provides no benefit.  Either way, you still might have to handle the exception. If init allocates memory, and then throws then what do you do that is any different from what you would have done if the constructor throws?  Creating an init function just gives you a false sense that everything is fine, but you still have the exact same kind of cleanup to do either way. With the init function you have even more to do because now you do have to destroy *p.